Finding a modelinstance in LIBGDX from a Scene by node id
I have loaded a 3d scene from Maya into Libgdx: It has two polygonal objects(meshes)
One object is labeled as: chamber
The other object: it has another name
I load the Maya scene as such:
sceneAsset = new GLTFLoader().load(Gdx.files.internal("myexports.gltf"));
scene = new Scene(sceneAsset.scene);
            sManager.addScene(scene);

Now, I know I can iterate through the names of the references within the model scene that was loaded as such:
 for(Node node : sceneAsset.scene.model.nodes){  // print some debug info on the file contents
                Gdx.app.log("Node ", node.id);                  
               
            }

I need to know the exact location of where each model within that scene was loaded. How can I find the exact location. From what I have read the models appear exactly where they were place when it was created in Maya. I need to know the location of say the model whose name is "head" in order for the game camera to look at the specific vector where it is located. How to find this specific vector?

Are you looking for How do I get the 3D coordinates of my model Instance?? If you want the position in world space, you may need to use the globalTransform as explained here.
